# Difficulty Plotting Periodic Function with Android GraphView Library

Tags: android-graphview

I'm trying to construct a graph that represents a set impulse delta functions by creating a set of line segments with the following code:

```
    series.appendData(new DataPoint(0,0), true, 30);

    series.appendData(new DataPoint(0,1), true, 30);
    series.appendData(new DataPoint(0,0), true, 30);
    series.appendData(new DataPoint(1,0), true, 30);

    series.appendData(new DataPoint(1,1), true, 30);
    series.appendData(new DataPoint(1,0), true, 30);
    series.appendData(new DataPoint(2,0), true, 30);
```

However, each vertical line segment beyond the first does not plot on the graph as illustrated in the attached screenshot. [image]

Perhaps you have some insight as why the vertical line segments are not being plotted.